# Reading OTP from Twilio using python

Tags: python, selenium, twilio, twilio-api

I am currently working in a web automation using selenium python-pytest framework. Here I have a scenario when after providing my phone number, an OTP will be generated and I need to get the OTP and put the same in a text box in the web application. I have seen some tutorial that how twilio works and I have learned that how to send OTP using Twilio library of python. But here the OTP should be sent by the web application itself after clicking some button but I am not sure how to retrieve the OTP in this case. Instead of my personal phone number, if I put the Twilio number in the phone number textbox and get the OTP there in my twilio profile, how to retrieve the same using python? Which API I need to hit to retrieve the OTP from the inbox of my twilio profile? Any leads will be much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

- https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-and-modify-message-history-python

This documentation is having all the code you need to read . Below is one sample taken from the above location to read message resource.

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages('MMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').fetch()

print(message.body)
```